# Is there an item that allows you to craft based on what's in nearby chests?

Tags: terraria

I think I saw some item that allowed you to craft items based on what is in nearby chests instead of only what's in your inventory. For instance, I'd like to be able to craft some cobalt armor when I have some cobalt bars in a chest within like 50 blocks but none in my inventory.

Does an item like that exist?

Answer (score 1):

It's not an item. This feature was added in the 1.3 update.

> You can now craft items from a chest while it is open without having to place its contents in the player inventory beforehand.

-- [Official Terraria Wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/1.3.0.1#Crafting)

Comment: Also, the other part of what he asked for, arbitrary unopened chests within a specific distance, is not available.

Comment: Can you confirm if this should apply to the console version?

Comment: @Timelord64 - version 1.3 has not yet been released for console. I think it's a reasonable assumption that it would have this feature.